# How to listen ONLY on specified ports?

Tags: mamp

I have the following specified in my vhosts file:

```
Listen 8585
NameVirtualHost *:8585

Listen 8888
NameVirtualHost *:8888

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8585>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test"
    ServerName www.test.me
    ServerAlias test.me
</VirtualHost>
```

This works as follows:

1. `localhost:8888` goes to the localhost location
2. `localhost:8585` goes to the `www.test.me` location
3. `test.me:8585` goes go the `www.test.me` location
4. `test.me:8888` doesn't go anywhere

What I'd like is that localhost only responds on port 8888 and ignores 8585 (just like test.me listens on 8585 but ignores 8888).

Not sure if this is doable and if so, how to set this up. Thanks for any suggestions!